# Re-defining the built-in `CharacterRange` for a range of 1500 or more

Tags: code-request, index

I have the following function (developed by @kglr), and now I need to use the same function with a list of 1043 characters rather than a limited number from `A` to `Z`:

```
grapH[mat_, dir_: "Column"][t_, v_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
  Module[
  {vertices = CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length@mat]], 
   comp = dir /. {"Column" -> VertexInComponent, 
   "Row" -> VertexOutComponent}, 
   gf = dir /. {"Column" -> AdjacencyGraph, 
   "Row" -> ReverseGraph@*AdjacencyGraph}, g}, 
   g = gf[vertices, 
   Transpose[UnitStep[Normalize[#, Total] - t] & /@ Transpose[mat]]];
   Subgraph[g, comp[g, v], opts]
   ];
```

As implied by:

```
CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length@mat]]
```

As long as the list from `A` to `Z` is greater or equal to `Length[mat]` where `mat` is a matrix, the `code` works as expected. But I have a matrix of dimensions (1050, 1050), and therefore the above `code` is not correct anymore.

I want to expand `CharacterRange[...]` comprising of letters like `A, a, B, b,...` to meet the size of my matrix.

```
characterRange[A_, Z_, n_]:= CharacterRange["A", "Z"] ...?
```

Clearly, `n=60` and `A1, A2,...A60,...,Z1,...,Z60` is an option, but I cannot combine letters with numbers to create `StringNames` such as `A1`. Any idea?

Comment: why not `"A" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[60]`?

Comment: @kglr: How can I repeat `"A" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[60]` for the entire 26 letters?

Comment: `StringJoin/@Tuples[{Alphabet[], Range[60]}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Alphabet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html) + [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) + [`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html):

```
StringJoin /@ Tuples[{Alphabet[], ToString /@ Range[5]}]
```

> ```
>  {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "c1",
>   "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "e1", "e2", 
>   "e3", "e4", "e5", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "g1", "g2", "g3", 
>   "g4", "g5", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", 
>   "i5", "j1", "j2", "j3", "j4", "j5", "k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5", 
>   "l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5", "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "n1", 
>   "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "o1", "o2", "o3", "o4", "o5", "p1", "p2", 
>   "p3", "p4", "p5", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5", "r1", "r2", "r3", 
>   "r4", "r5", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", 
>   "t5", "u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u5", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", 
>   "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "y1", 
>   "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "z1", "z2", "z3", "z4", "z5"}
> ```

You can also use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
 Flatten@Outer[StringJoin, Alphabet[], ToString /@ Range[5]] == %
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Adding upper case letters you can get 3120 combinations:

```
Flatten[Outer[StringJoin, Flatten[{#, ToUpperCase@#} &@Alphabet[]], 
   ToString /@ Range[60]]] // Length
```

> ```
>  3120
> ```

Add Greek letters to get 4560 combinations:

```
Flatten[Outer[StringJoin, 
   Flatten[{{#, ToUpperCase@#} &@Alphabet[], Alphabet[ "Greek"]}], 
   ToString /@ Range[60]]] // Length
```

> ```
>  4560
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
Table[char <> ToString[num],
  {char, CharacterRange["A", "Z"]~Join~CharacterRange["a", "z"]},
  {num, 60}
]~Flatten~1

(* Out:
{"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", ..., "Z59", "Z60", "a1", "a2", ..., "z60"}
*)
```